# Where is the OpenGL context stored?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am fairly new to OpenGL and have been using GLFW combined with GLEW to create and display OpenGL contexts. The following code snippet shows how I create a window and use it for OpenGL.

```
GLFWwindow* window;

if (!glfwInit())
{
    return -1;
}

window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Hello OpenGL", NULL, NULL);

if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

GLenum err = glewInit();

if (err != GLEW_OK)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
```

How is `glewInit` able to fetch the window/context and use it to initialize without myself having to pass any additional arguments to it?

I can only imagine that when we call the `glfwMakeContextCurrent` function it somehow stores the context somewhere within my process for later use, but no documentation shows this.

Comment: Essentially all OpenGL functions are pointers thereof; glew 'initialises' those pointers such that they behave like functions while in fact they are simply references to functions already loaded in memory. The thing is, glew isn't a viable API because it provides a slight overhead and doesn't cover everything in OpenGL. It's best to use something more up-to-date like `glbinding`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current OpenGL context is a global (or more to the point, `thread_local`) "variable" of sorts. All OpenGL functions act on whatever context is active in the current thread at the moment.

This includes the OpenGL calls that GLEW makes.